# How does one write a combinatoric argument to use as a proof for the following example?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

$0\binom{n}{0}+ 1\binom{n}{1}+ 2\binom{n}{2}+...+(n-1)\binom{n}{n-1}+ n\binom{n}{n}= n2^{n-1}$

I was able to prove it by induction doing some manipulation. But, combinatoric arguments are my weakness. If someone could help me out on this particular problem as well as any pointer on how to approach these type of arguments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can find similar proofs in the book "Proofs that really count" by Arthur T Benjamin and Jennifer J Quinn, Dolicani Mathematical Expositions, published by the Mathematical Association of America.

Answer (score 1):

Let us count the number of ways to form a committee from a set of $n$ people with one of them designated as the leader. If the committee has $k$ people, the number of ways of choosing the committee is $\binom{n}{k}$ and one of them can be chosen as their leader in $k$ ways and the total number of ways is $\sum k\binom{n}{k}$.  On the other hand, let us first choose the leader and then the committee. The leader can be chosen in $n$ ways and the committee can be any subset of the remaining $n−1$ people and hence this can be done in $n2^{n-1}$ ways.